# Need some help with focusing/clarifying a question

Tags: discussion

See here:
[Where should a plugin or widget cache its results?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55404/where-should-a-plugin-or-widget-cache-its-results)

I'm trying to help the OP clarify/focus the question, but I'm struggling. As it is, it's bordering on *not a real question*, due to its vagueness. There is definitely a good question in here, but I could use some help getting it where it needs to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that very *general* questions get less traction, often because the answers border on opinion rather than experience.

Specific questions often cause the light-bulb to go off because someone has been in the exact same scenario and thus knows from memory how to handle it with a real answer.

What I have tried to do a few times in comments ( I added one to your above link) is try to get the user to make the question more real-world and specific.

Comment: Thanks for the help!